# Wingdings font Family not supported by mozilla firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm not able to find an exact substitute for the wingding font family in firefox browser. After intensive web search also , i haven't found any success . Kindly help me out asap.

Comment: winging is not a family, but a discrete font, based on Dingbats. It is not compatible with other fonts as would form a family, because it only expresses symbolic characters, not alphabetic characters. Look into using unicode expression of those characters instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbats_%28Unicode_block%29#Unicode_dingbats

Answer (score 4):

Firefox intentionally refuses to play font tricks that fool other browsers, such as `<font face=Wingdings>%</font>`. This element asks for a rendering of the percent sign “%” using the Wingdings font. It does not contain a glyph for that character, so Firefox adequately ignores the request and uses some default font instead. Other browsers instead display whatever happens to be in Wingdings at code position 0x25, which should be used for the percent sign. Such tricks were common in the past, but they work against the principles of the web.

If you would like to change Firefox behavior in this respect, I’m afraid you would need to dig into its code and modify it. There does not seem to be any setting for this.

If you wish to use Wingdings symbols as an author of HTML documents, the practical choice is to use images instead. They are iconic symbols rather than “true” characters anyway.

Many Wingdings symbols have been [encoded in Unicode](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html), and in theory you could use e.g. `&#x1f514;` for the symbol that appears at 0x25 in Wingdings. In practice, Firefox still won’t use Wingdings for it, but it uses some properly encoded font in the system, if available, to render it. But browsers often fail with such characters, even if a suitable font exists in the system.